# Ruby (Rock, Paper, Scissors)

Tags: ruby

Hey I am new to ruby and I have sat for a long time trying to find out what I've done wrong in this code, there isn't any error but it isn't giving me my desired output as a normal game of rock paper scissors.
Here is my code:

```
puts "Rock, Paper or Scissors"
choice = gets.chomp
cchoice = ["Rock", "Paper","Scissors"]
comp = rand(1..3)
won = false


puts "Computer chose #{cchoice[comp]}"
if (choice == "Rock")
    if (comp == 2)
        won = false
    end
    if (comp == 3)
        won = true
    end
elsif (choice == "Paper")
    if (comp == 3)
        won = false
    end
    if (comp == 1)
        won = true
    end
elsif (choice == "Scissors")
    if (comp == 1)
        won = false
    end
    if (comp == 2)
        won = true
    end
else
    puts "I dont know what that means so-"
end

if (won)
    puts "YOU WON!!!"
else
    puts "You lost.."
end
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules of rock, paper, scissors can be expressed as a simple hash:

```
conditions = {
  "Rock" => "Scissors",
  "Paper" =>  "Rock",
  "Scissors" => "Paper"
}
```

So you can simply check if one player won over the other with:

```
if conditions[player_1] == player_2
  puts "Player one wins!"
elsif player_1 == player_2
  puts "Its a draw!"
else
  puts "Player two wins!"
end
```

This is far less complex then a tree of nested if/else statements.

```
conditions = {
  "Rock": "Scissors",
  "Paper": "Rock",
  "Scissors": "Paper"
}

puts "Rock, Paper or Scissors"
choice = gets.chomp.capitalize
cchoice = conditions.keys.sample
puts "Computer chose #{ cchoice }"
  
if conditions[choice] == cchoice
  puts "You won!"
elsif cchoice == choice
  puts "Its a draw."
elsif conditions[cchoice] == choice
  puts "You lost."
else
  puts "#{choice} is not a valid option"
end
```

This covers the four potential outcomes which are:

- win
- loss
- draw
- bad input (this could also be handled with controll flow like break/throw/catch)

Also instead of `rand` you can use `Array#sample` to select a random element from the keys of the hash which avoids the need to use array indices.

Comment: If you want a challenge then put this in a loop so that the game will ask the player to try again if they choose an invalid choice and so that it also asks if they want to play again.

Answer (score 3):

Your random number generator generates numbers between 1-3, it should be between 0-2 since you are trying to index a list

```
comp = rand(0..2)
```

Also change the comparison in the if clause to reflect the above change,

Another thing you might have forgot is the draw condition (if both select the same thing)